# Multithreading and SQLAlchemy: How to prevent DB access errors?

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**TL;DR:**

**How do I prevent DB access issues when calling a PostgreSQL database from multiple threads in Python using SQLAlchemy?**

**The details:**

I am developing a *Python* software that uses *Multithreading* (concurrent.futures ThreadPool) - but I am by no means an expert in anything.

I also use *SQLAlchemy* to communicate with a *PostgreSQL* database (using pg8000).

Because I wanted to keep all my database stuff separate from all the rest, **all** the SQLAlchemy code sits in a Python module that I called db_manager.py. In here you will find the declarative base, the create_engine() call but also loads of methods to get stuff or store stuff in the database. Each method here ends with:

```
session.commit()
```

(unless I just query the database).

Each thread then would call the db_manager module to interact with the database, e.g.:

```
db_manager.getSomethingFromDB(...)
```

I created a little drawing to illustrate the architecture.

**The problem:**

Now the problem I run into is that these database calls seem to clash sometimes.
What is the best way of dealing with multithreading, SQLAlchemy, and PostgreSQL?

**Some ideas:**

- Currently, my db_manager accesses the PostgreSQL as a specific user (pg8000 appears to require this). Is that a problem? Should each thread be its own user? Or can this not be causing problems? If each thread needs to be its own database user, I would probably no longer be able to have all my database stuff in one single module.
- I failed to define rollbacks for each commit. I just noticed this is causing problems this any error prevents any further database access.

[image: Illustration of the architecture]

Comment: By clash, do you mean concurrent update errors or something else? Can you post the specific error message?

Comment: @univerio: I am sorry. I should have included that in my post. I am currently running into an error message that prevents me from running into earlier errors.
The current error message is:

`SAWarning: Usage of the 'Session.add()' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead.
  % method)
`

Comment: Bear with me:
I will update shortly. I am tracking down the source of this error.

Comment: It looks like the underlying cause of my problems might not be concurrency after all. I identified some causes and eliminated the problems but I am stuck with this one here:

`This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: 
(pg8000.core.ProgrammingError) ('ERROR', 'ERROR', '22P02', 'invalid input syntax for integer: "https://3dprintingindustry.com/"', 'numutils.c', '62', 'pg_atoi', '', '')`

Comment: Finally, I got back to my old problem. This it is:

`A transaction is already begun.  Use subtransactions=True to allow subtransactions.`

and

`This session is in 'prepared' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.`

Comment: That's most likely because you're trying to use the same session across different threads. Try using [scoped sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right.
Stupid question:
Do I instantiate this `some_session = Session()` _once_ in my db_manager? Or do I do this for _each_ method in the db_manager in which I do something with the database?

Comment: See [When do I construct a `Session`, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it). For your particular purpose, it means you should at least create a session for each thread (i.e. each method). Using `scoped_session` will make it a lot easier.

Comment: One last question:
I run into the problem that my method calls session.add() and session.rollback() no longer work using the new way. Any idea why that might be? I feel very stupid right now.
Python things they would be attributes for some reason:
`session.add(pattern)  
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: Well, `add` *is* an attribute on `session`; it just happens to also be a function. Not sure why you're running into that; how are you constructing `session`?

Comment: I am the dumbest person on the planet. I declared a class Session. And Python obviously had to think I was looking for attributes in that class. I need an expert programming nanny like you. Thank you for your help! I feel terrible.